# Rshiny : y axis based on selectinput for barplot but with a fixed x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, bar-chart, selectinput

Here is my data :

```
years   bank    hospital    school  police  housing

2016    125       436        248    7.612   2.535
2017    167       497        281    8.215   3.145
2018    6064      2792      7564    38015   329
2019    2.972     3.070     14.771  40.180  371
2020    193       2.417     10.472  47.894  366



dput(fund)
structure(list(sector = c(2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020), bank = c(125.2243, 
167.4207, 6064.2903, 2971.6812, 192.7661), hospital = c(435.6579, 
496.557, 2791.8501, 3070.4745, 2416.9531), school = c(248.476, 
281.4527, 7564.4581, 14770.9388, 10471.76), police = c(7612.456, 
8215.4141, 38014.6638, 40179.971, 47894.2436), housing = c(2534.8019, 
3145.1998, 328.9033, 370.7749, 365.9282)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

and this is the code I made (I'm stuck at the server part):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Fund"),
                selectInput(
                  inputId = "varbar1",
                  "choose....",
                  choices = c('bank',
                              'hospital',
                              'school',
                              'police',
                              'housing'
                  ),selectize=FALSE),
                plotOutput("bar1"))
server <- function(input, output) {
  
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I want my output to be like this :

[image]

Can someone tell me how can this work especially the coding in the server section please

Answer (score 3):

The `server` part can be

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$bar1 <- renderPlot({
    
    barplot(fund[[input$varbar1]], names.arg = fund$sector, col = "red")
  })
  
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

-output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i found another solution for this problem, but this time i use ggplot2 and reshape2 here is the code :

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Fund"),
                selectInput(
                  inputId = "varbar1",
                  "choose....",
                  choices = c('bank',
                              'hospital',
                              'school',
                              'police',
                              'housing'
                  ),selectize=FALSE),
                plotOutput("bar1"))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$bar1<-renderPlot({

    #reshape data
    dfm <- melt(fund[,c("sector",input$varbar1)],id.vars = 1)

    #barplot
    ggplot(dfm,aes(x = factor(sector),y = value)) + 
      geom_bar(aes(fill = variable),stat = "identity",position = "dodge") + 
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

and here is the result :
[image]